# D3.js x-axis in days

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3 and I'm now trying to create an x-axis that plots between two dates, and prints out the days on the x-axis. I'm currently loading the dates values via a JavaScript object `data.start` `data.end`. The `data.start` gets today's date, and the `data.end` get its value from a date picker input (in the code below they get the same values but it works). They are working as they should, and if I console log them I get the valid dates as strings. Now if I try to create a x-axis `.scaleTime()` between these two string dates then the x-axis doesn't output anything. If I on the other hand use a JavaScript date object as the start, and end dates in the `.domain` I do get an output. Here is some sample code, not of course my entire `.js` file but just the things that *"should"* matter.

```
function getDate() {
    const dateObj = new Date();

    let d = String(dateObj.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    let m = String(dateObj.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    let y = dateObj.getFullYear();

    return y + '-' + m + '-' + d;
}

let data = {
    start: getDate(),
    end: getDate(),
    currency: currDropdown,
    granularity: 86400
};

const xScale = d3
   .scaleTime()
   .domain([data.start, data.end])
   .range([0, width - 100]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by _x-axis doesn't output anything_ ? Where is your axis rendering code (`d3.select(...).append('g').call(axis)` ?

Comment: I think you might be confusing the terms "scale" and "axis" a scale is a function that converts from the data domain, in this case time, to an output range, in this case screen pixels. You can use a scale to draw an axis, a visual representation of that scale. Here are the docs for d3-axis: https://github.com/d3/d3-axis